# Getting decimals from text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an HTML element ("summary-payment") which contains the text: "Pay £100.00", for example.

I have managed to get the number 100 from this, as follows:

```
function getPaymentAmount(paymentAmount) {
    var stringTotal = $("#paymentBtn").text();
    var extractIntFromTotal = stringTotal.match(/\d+/)[0];
    return extractIntFromTotal;
}
```

However, I'd like to get the decimal 100.00 back. I have tried adding onto the index but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please help? I am very new to javascript.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is there any way I could get the decimal back, even if the starting number was 100.34 for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to amend your regular expression to include the decimals:

```js
function getPaymentAmount(paymentAmount) {
  return paymentAmount.match(/\d+[.,]?\d{2}?/)[0];
}

console.log(getPaymentAmount('Pay £100.00'));
console.log(getPaymentAmount('Pay £215'));
console.log(getPaymentAmount('Lorem ipsum $500.33 dolor sit'));
```

Comment: If you want to match `,` as decimal separator, you can update the reges `\d+[.,]?\d{2}`. This will also match whole numbers like "Pay $123"

Comment: @shree33 good point for cultures which use the `,` as the decimal separator. I updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `split()` and then `pop()`:

```js
function getPaymentAmount(paymentAmount) {
    var stringTotal = 'Pay £100.00'; 
    var extractIntFromTotal = stringTotal.split('£').pop();
    return extractIntFromTotal;
}

console.log(getPaymentAmount());
```

Comment: What happens if the value is in $? Or if there's text after the price? I would assume the OP used a regex for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var stringTotal = "Pay £100.00";
 var thenum = stringTotal.replace( /^\D+/g, ''); // replace all leading non-digits with nothing

 console.log(thenum);
```